# testing coding bat problems in my own compiler

Tags: java

If you're not familiar with codingbat, you basically just enter something like this

```
public int[] post4(int[] nums) {
int four = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
if(nums[i] == 4) {
four = i;
}
}

four++;
int[] result = new int[nums.length - four];

for(int i = four; i < nums.length; i++) {
result[i - four] = nums[i];
}

    return result;
}
```

into a little box to solve a coding problem, then click "Go" and it will either come up with errors or say you got it right. My question is, I want to test the above code in MY OWN compiler (such as Eclipse, BlueJay, etc) so how would I do that? When I pasted it verbatim it didn't work, so does it need a class header? public static void main(String[] args)? a separate tester class?

I know the particular solution above is correct, I just want to test future ones in my own compiler.

Here's a link to this specific question: http://codingbat.com/prob/p164144

So what exactly do I have to put in to make my code run?

Comment: Coding Bat isn't a complete programming course, it's useful for practicing coding but you'll need a more through tutorial that takes you through the process of installing a working environment, the basic of how the main class are found and loaded, compiling and executing, and all that.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a valid Java-File with valid syntax.

So in your case: You'll need a class to put everything in and you'll propably want to ad a Main-Method which calls the `post4`-Method.

Comment: `public class post4T1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        public int post4(int[] nums) {`it came up with an error at the third line saying illegal start of expression. :( I'm not sure if I'm doing this right

Comment: I cannot see an error in what you wrote here. I recommend looking at some Java hello-world, it'll probably help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed eclipse already, I suggest you do. It is very simple to use and operate, and there a multitude of subjects on the subject. However, the basic class structure is as follows.

```
public class CLASSNAME {

    public static void main(String[] args) { //This runs at runtime first
    // place any code here you want to run at runtime.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you look for something like this:

```
package myjavacode;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass app = new MyClass();

    // (1) declare array with values
    int[] inputArray = new int[]{1,2,3};

    // (2) run the method and print result (needs to convert to String before)
    int[] output = app.post4(inputArray);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(output));
}

    // Your method goes here
    public int[] post4(int[] nums) {
        int four = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] == 4) {
                four = i;
            }
        }

        four++;
        int[] result = new int[nums.length - four];

        for (int i = four; i < nums.length; i++) {
            result[i - four] = nums[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You could also make your method static in which case you wouldn't have to create an instance of `MyClass()`.